# When building a language & alphabet (especially between species) what range of phonemes (mainly consonants) should be included?

Tags: language, interspecies-relations

Most languages on earth do not have every phoneme. When creating a new language, how do I decide which ones to choose? How should I manage the relationship between different languages? I have a race of wolf-people as well as a race of humans & I'm not sure how to go about relating the wolf phonemes (which will probably be a lot more vowel, tone, & duration based) to human phonemes? The race I'm creating the language for is from the book series Codex Alera. Canim, (KAH-nimm). I'm considering making a TV series which I will need a language for.

I'm basing the writing style off of Futhark, because the characters have no horizontal lines. When writing in wood: horizontal lines would be invisible within the grain. This is why Futhark (& soon-to-be Canish) have only diagonal & vertical lines. They go against the grain & pop out visually. Even if Canim cannot produce the sounds of Futhark I can still use the characters as inspiration. Hindi, Finnish, & Astonian might be good languages to relate dog sounds to human mouths.

Some words & names include: Tavar, Gadara, Sa/Sar, La/Lar, Gradash, Varg, Sarl, Nasaug, Sochar-Lar (Socha-La), Lararl, Kharsh, Marok, Narash, Shaur, Maraul, Tarsh, Shuar, Molvar, & Anag. From these words we can assume that the phonemes include at least:

- **"ta"** probably not "ta/tha" on the teeth as in the french word for "tea" due to carnivore teeth.
- **"va"** but with the bottom lip in front of the teeth instead of under it.
- **"ra"** & probably several different kinds of "r"s. I have a speech impediment with my "r"s so I typically use my lip & teeth to make the english "r". Canim would probably also have the uvular "r"s, especially trills. The soft french "r", the arabic french "r", & the smooth trilled french "r" would all be very useful. I definitely believe that they would have a plethora of different "r"s.
- **"da"** This one is just "ta" with vocals. Both of them have very sharp sounds though, & dogs struggle to hear consonants. I may consider doing away with all of the voiced vs unvoiced sounds & lump them all in the same category. "Pa" & "ba"? Same sound.
- **"ra"** as in the Japanese r/l or only one of the Spanish "r" trills. That depends on the tongue though. A thin tongue might not work as well.
- **"Sa"** might be lisped or whistled. I doubt that "s" would be a common letter.
- **"La"** but none of the dental "l"s.
- **"Ga"** the "g" can have an "r" immediately after. Dogs' tongues are huge so tbh I think they would have a ton of "g" sounds, like how Korean has several (including "ka"). I believe they would also have those "h" sounds that are kind of growly. Maybe like the "tl" of quetzalcoatl or axolotl. (Btw "axolotl" os pronounced more like "ashochle".) I would go so far as to say that your different "ranges" of Canim would have regional dialects. Some might use velar "g"s while others might use uvular (or even dental, considering their tongues) "g"s & "g"-like sounds.
- **"sha"** which is one I'm skeptical about. I believe it is
  post-alveolar. Maybe this is one of their versions of "s" because
  they cannot pronounce other "s"s.
- **"Ma"** Bilabial sounds (lip on lip) might be uncommon. They might also only have bilabial stops. I'm not entirely sure if muzzled animals regularly breathe through their noses, but if they don't: it would be more like a human with a cold. "M" becomes "b". Not to mention lip dexterity. We say cats make "meow" sounds so Canim might be able to have an "m".
- **"Na"** This sound would definitely have a few iterations. Dogs have such long tongues, it is similar to "g" & "k" with the "n" being at the front & "ng" being at the back. In fact, if a dog could put the tip of its tongue anywhere from the teeth to the back of the hard palate like humans (or farther), but ALSO have the tongue at a curve so that the middle of the tongue can touch those same places, then they might be able to make a series of "n" sounds as well as a series of "ng" sounds.
- **"Varg"** might actually be pronounced like a pirate's "argh" rather than with the english "r" or the sharp "g" that is just a voiced "k". The species that speaks this language is, after all, a wolf species. Maybe like the velar (voiced or unvoiced) non-sibilant fricatives. I really have velar sounds bouncing around in my head for this.
- **"Sarl"** is probably not pronounced like "parlay" in english. Possibly like "parlé" in french. It could be the soft "peanut butter on the roof of your mouth" "r", the soft trill, or the rough "h"-like trill. If Alerans/humans say it, they would definitely use the soft "r", regardless of whether it is growling or not.
- **"Kharsh"** has an interesting spelling. Why the "h"? Is it to emphasize the fact that it is unvoiced? Is it to imply that the "k" is not a stop? If so, then it would be more like "charsh" from "loch" or "gharsh" from pirate "argh". Again, dogs struggle to differentiate consonants.
- **"Marok"** might have similar sounds for the "r" & the "k" if they are pronounced like "argh" & "loch". "Marghogh" might sound like Magok,Marok, or Maror to us, but to people who are used to that sound (especially a species that struggles with consonants) it may sound more varied.
- **"Molvar"** So another person making a muzzled language said they ruled out "v" (& the unvoiced "f") but the Canim have that sound. Not only that but the "l" is able to be used before it. I have mentioned this before, I'm sure: "v" might be able to be pronounced if the bottom lip is in front of the teeth rather than below. The "l" & "v" also have to be compatible. "olv" is a very human sound & I doubt a snouted animal would be able to make those sounds the way humans think of them.

(I already did some research on this: I need(ed) information about what sounds dogs could physically make, but all of the information online was "If your dog [whimpers, yips, barks, etc] it means that they are [happy, feeling threatened, etc]." Yeah, thanks, but what phonetic sounds are involved in a bark?)

Keep your eyes out for a follow-up question about words & language rather than just phonemes!

Comment: Welcome! These are a lot of questions, and more about the specifics of the language rather than its role in a fictional world. Have you considered asking this on [conlang.SE](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: *"Phoneme"* : Rather than my own words I'll use Googles *"distinct units of sound in a specified language that distinguish one word from another, for example p, b, d, and t in the English words pad, pat, bad, and bat"* / so that is going to depend entirely on what sounds both of the two species can actually make with their vocal (or other sound making) apparatus / so as worded your question is unanswerable, we need to know what sounds your wolf-people can make / your creation so your choice really, you can claim any minor divergence in tongue & other vocal apparatus to normal wolves you like.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that you'd want to include the phonemes of the language in the writing system (if the language uses an alphabet for writing (some languages don't have an alphabet)). You will have to exercise your authorial discretion to decide what phonemes are used by your language. Questions where the answer is up to authorial discretion aren't a good fit for this site since they result in many equally valid answers.

Comment: If your two species have significantly different vocal abilities it's going to be a lot easier & perhaps make more sense to simply have a large number of them be bilingual & understand both languages, they speak their own to each other & understand the reply in the other.

Comment: *"Most languages on earth do not have every phoneme":* **No** language on Earth has all the phonemes present in all the other languages. Duh. *"Relating the wolf phonemes to human phonemes":* This is easy. There is no relationship. *"When building an alphabet, what range of phonemes should be included":* Ideally, all of them. But in practice, most alphabets assign multiple phonemes to the same letter. For example, the Latin alphabet makes do with 5 letters for 10 different Latin vowels + 2 semivowels; the Greek alphabet makes do with 7 letters for 11 different Greek vowels + 2 semivowels.

Comment: Perhaps our sister site [conlang.se] might be informative and of help to you.

Comment: Why would questions about language design nessecarily yield more than one answer and  be closed as "opinion based" ..  and questions about weapon design, or creature design yield only one answer and not be opinion based, I wonder ? voted against the close proposal.

Comment: @Goodies: How did you vote against the close proposal? I don't know how to do that. (And the question needs to be closed because there are already answers on this site addressing the same issues.)

Comment: @AlexP -- You "vote against" the proposal by clicking "vote to leave open".

Comment: @elemtilas: I must have a case of User Interface Deficit Disorder. I do not see any "vote to leave open". Under the question I see Share Edit Follow Close Flag. If I click Close I get a box which only allows me to select one of five reasons for closing, and the only buttons are × to close the box with no action, Vote to close, and Cancel.

Comment: @AlexP -- Ah! When you're in the **Close Votes** review queue, there's a box on the right labelled **Actions**. The first one is *Leave Open*. If you click on that you've "voted against" the proposed closure. Only positive votes --- those critical five votes required to close a query --- count. "Voting against" closure is simply a feel good measure. Clicking on the *Close(x)* link presupposes that your intention is to close the query, so there's no reason to present you with the option to leave it open!

Comment: @elemtilas This is not correct. Please read the StackExchange FAQ: [If the question doesn't meet the criteria for any close reason, choose **Leave open**. If enough users choose this option, the question will be dismissed from the review queue.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @Otkin -- Oo, I wasn't aware of that! I've never seen any question be "dismissed" from the queue (once you take any action, the query disappears from your own queue anyway). So, apparently it's [three users who are enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139834/what-exactly-happens-with-the-button-leave-open-previously-do-not-close) to dismiss it from the queue. However, I stand by characterising that vote as a "feel good" action because "leave open" votes don't actually affect or counter the number of close votes. Also, no one can see how many "leave open" votes have been cast.

Comment: @elemtilas The question is removed from the review queue. And people need to go directly to the question if they still want to close it. This makes a huge difference on big stacks. The WB.SE is too small with only a dozen questions per day, so this measure is not as effective. However, it still lowers the chances of questions being closed.

Comment: @Otkin -- Possibly, though I think you might be righter when it comes to high volume forums. The fact that questions here remain on the first page for sometimes several days easily counteracts any influence that removing it from the queue would have. Also: review queues are not sure indicators that a question will be more or less likely to be closed. I almost never look in the review queues at all, and never first. I'm far more likely to encounter a question in the close process simply because it's being actively downvoted or it's on the first page where I'm very likely to read it!

Comment: Writing is an encoding of phonemes by images; Silbo Gomero is an encoding of phonemes by whistles.  If people can understand the latter, then we can understand an encoding of human phonemes by wolf phonemes.

Comment: Thanks for the conlang suggestion!

Comment: & sorry to everyone if my question was difficult to understand/answer or improperly suited for this subsite. I'm new here & didn't know there was an option for constructed languages. It has been super helpful to get all these different thoughts to consider

Comment: @thatonefriend61 for this question, I'd suggest to change the term "phoneme" into "consonant". All your examples refer to (initial) consonants. You mension labial m several times, but you forgot the labial "b" and "p" which may be easier for canines, because they won't need firm and prolonged closure of the lips. Dog's lips have bumps, letting the air through. There's a nice website about dog's lips  https://pawleaks.com/do-dogs-have-lips/

Comment: @Goodies Thanks for the suggestion! I still want vowels, but I'm sure they will be a lot easier for me to figure out on my own.  (The b/p/m thing is totally true! I did think about that a bit but I guess I focused too much on the m.)

Comment: @thatonefriend61 I finished my answer, worked out some of my above remarks.

Answer (score 2):

#### Build the Bridge :: They will come

Since this is worldbuilding, I'm going to present a worldbuilding perspective, rather than an invented language perspective.

Essentially, languages of the sort you're describing serve as bridges between cultures and races of people. Two races in sufficient contact that they would find some sort of common interlanguage to be useful indicates that there is likely some kind of shared experience. Perhaps they are two races who inhabit a fantasy world, or two cultures that meet for trade and intercourse in a space station, or perhaps one has arrived on the other's planet for the first time and thought they would stop by and say howdy.

Given your descriptions of the two races, and the fact that you have presupposed that both have a compatible language capacity, compatible cognitive abilities and so forth, I think your job will be fairly easy.

The language itself doesn't have to be constrained by this or that set of phonemes. Humans quite naturally build interlanguages --- pidgins --- very easily when two groups sharing no common language meet. Culturally, you're going to be more interested in the two races points of commonality: why are they in contact and what do they need or want from each other?

You're going to become very interested in lupine anatomy and physiology to give you an idea how a wolf makes sounds; and then will likely expand from there to determine which sounds a wolf could make would make it into a language. So, you'll want to consider the wolf folk's language in and of itself. You'll also want to consider the human folk's language on its own as well. Once you've got an idea of which sounds they use in their respective native languages, you'll be able to discover how each will handle any language sounds the other can make.

Your task, in so far as worldbuilding goes, won't be so much picking from the list of all phonemes on the IPA chart, as it would be discovering which phonemes from the two lists you've already got will best facilitate communication between the two groups.

Comment: Makes me think on what they did with the film "Solo", Chewbacca's meeting with Han, the sound of Chewie's name in his (?) own language compared to Han's  translation - it was a heavily reinterpreted instance of the same sounds, makes your point I think. But they started with some common languages of course.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. -- That's the basic idea!

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this & find it useful. I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "interlanguage" though. Is that like the Metis dialect with Cree, Indigenous, English, & French words all mixed together? Next, do you have any good places I can research physiology? Last, this is a language I'm creating for the Canim in my Codex Alera film/series adaptation so I already have some source material, yay!

Answer (score 1):

Let's do 3 groups of phonemes, and relate them to the canine mouth..

**Voiceless consonants**

With their agile tongue, dogs will be able to perform a lot of consonant phonemes, like humans do. Most of your examples, actually.. and probably a lot more. Sounds like c, d, G (harsh), g, h, sj, zj, j, k, r, s, t are certainly doable.

Phonemes "w" and "v" will be softer, or too difficult. Human teeth have a flat top, canine teeth are pointy. It will be difficult to let it sound loud.. or they'll trick it.

Some consonants will be hard. Canines don't close their lips perfectly, like we can. A dog will have to do a trick, to perform phonemes that sound like b or p: humans can build up pressure and release it, a dog can't do that easily. Both "b" and  "p" will be realized far up front, using only the air enclosed behind the lips.

**Voiced consonants**

There will always be air leaking through the teeth and through the [bumped lips](https://pawleaks.com/do-dogs-have-lips/) on the side of the mouth. The "m" will probably be out of reach for canines.

Also, (imho) a dog will have difficulties doing z, l, n sounds, which are realized using the tongue, but they are *voiced consonants*, which have properties of..

**Vowels**

You did not mention vowels in your list. These are really difficult for most animals having large teeth. The teeth don't allow the animal to close the mouth on either side..

Vowels and *voiced* consonants are actually 2 resonances of the mouth cavity, determined by width and height of that cavity. There should be 4 *closed* wands for 2 formants.

Technically, you'll get 2 spectral peaks. These peaks characterize the vowel for the listener. For English vowels, the result voiced phonemes for F1 (horizontal) and F2 (vertical) are ordered as follows:

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_diagram

Humans have flat, straight lips. When they produce a vowel, with only the lips opened, they will have both resonances at their disposal. Humans also have musculature to manipulate these two dimensions independently, that is why we can make a *very wide range* of vowels, canines will have limited variation in above triangle.

When canines close their mouth, they will only have one prominent formant, in vertical direction. That is not sufficient to make a wide range of different vowels.

**Vowels that canines will be able to do: listen to howling and crying.**

Vowels like è (pair) and e (hay) need two strong formants, you won't hear them from dogs. But take the above vowel diagram, draw a straight horizontal line across. Canines will be able to produce (only) these vowels, depending on their mouth size. It should be vowels with a pronounced, *single* formant, something like **U** (like in do) or **u** (phonetic: y, like German ü not in English) or **i**.  Canines *howl* and *cry* these sounds, there will be many examples on Youtube to listen to.

**Nasals**

A third "nasal formant" does exist.. The nasal formant is made by humans, using the nasal cavity for resonance. It can produce phoneme "ng" like in "thing" and in fact "n" is nasal as well. I think it won't work in dogs, because their nose is very separate. Not sure though..

Comment: !!!!!!! THIS IS SO SUPER USEFUL! Tysm for the in depth answer, I am so excited to translate this into my writing! Vowels on youtube will be pretty easy to access. Thanks for mentioning nasal stuff & lips! Those were great points. Since I am a human, I think I will be able to translate Canim sounds into human/latin sounds just as well as the humans in my world. This was a huge help & I think I just need to double down & write now.

Comment: Thx @thatonefriend61, hope you'll upvote it.. As for consonants, keep in mind dogs could use tricks humans won't use and achieve the same sound. When you look at the mouth of a parrot, biologically, you don't expect advanced things.. but they can learn a lot !